# Better way to do predicate assignment in C?

Tags: c

What I'm trying to do is avoid the following:

```
if(*ptr > 128) {
   number = 5;
}
```

Such code performs poorly when there's no clear pattern as to which way the branch will go. What I came up with is this:

```
int arr[] = { number, 5 };
int cond = *ptr > 128;
number = arr[cond];
```

Based on my testing, that runs more than twice as fast as doing the conditional when the input is random. What I'm wondering is if there's a more clever way to do this, perhaps using bitwise operators.

Comment: Performs poorly with what compiler and on what hardware?

Comment: Unless you are in an embedded real time environment where one tenth of a  bee's "you know what" matters, stick with the first method. Have you tried `number=(*ptr>128)?5:number;` ?

Comment: Similar but not identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798601/conditional-using-bitwise-operators but I think you'd get the idea

Comment: The compiler is gcc and the hardware (that I'm using) is a Core i5.

Comment: I would expect your second version to run slower than the first.

Comment: Did you enable the optimizations? I wouldn't be surprised if a recent compiler generated some equivalent branchless code by itself.

Comment: @John,  it makes a big difference if you are doing image processing on a high end PC,  and your code using ?: is still a branch.

Comment: GCC on my machine gives me `cmovlel` without branching at `-O3`.

Comment: I think the compiler will make use of the CMOV instruction if I compile to x86-64. I'm coding in a 32-bit environment though.

Comment: @cleong: `-arch i386` still gave me the CMOV instruction.

Comment: @cleong: if you drop support for ancient processors you can have `cmov` also on regular x86. `-march=i686` should do the trick.

Comment: If this level of optimization matters, I can't help but think you should just drop to assembly language for a few instructions. That would probably be more readable and maintainable than the code you're proposing.

Comment: If you are using GCC compiler, you can use the builtins(`__builtin_expect()`) to tell compiler which branch is your probable want, then the compiler will optimize your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clever compiler should definitely compile this to a conditional move with the right optimization settings; check the disassembly to be sure.

There is this branchless solution:

```
int mask = -(*ptr > 128);
number = (number & mask) | (5 & ~mask);
```

The last line can also be

```
number = ((mask & (number ^ 5)) ^ 5);
```

if you're looking to use one less operation. But, *caveat emptor*, the compiler won't be able to optimize either of these nearly as well. You are best leaving this particular optimization for the compiler to worry about, unless you specifically know that the compiler is unable to make the optimization (in that case, you may want to check your compiler version or flags).

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, going to the stack appears to be somewhat faster.